# Operation not permitted: '/usr/local/bin/python' when using flask in python docker (image built by gitlab-ci)

Tags: python-3.x, docker, gitlab-ci

On my machine, it works, and when trying to build the image by gitlab-ci, the previous message arrives at runtime.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir flask
COPY client.py
CMD ["python", "client.py"]
```

client.py

```
from flask import Flask
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, debug = True)
```

(I left only what is needed to have the error)

Note: the docker image is built with kaniko build

The error appears at line "app.run ..."

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer, and thought I would post to help people who would have the same problem:

Although I use "python:latest" in the Dockerfile in both cases, it is not the same python docker image used on my server and on gitlab runner;

I tried to fix python version ("python:3.11") but same behaviour.

Finally, I checked OS in both containers with following command:

```
cat /etc/os-release | grep PRETTY_NAME
```

and found this:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
```

on my server, and

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bookworm)"
```

on gitlab-ci

**setting full python version in Dockerfile solved the problem**:

```
FROM python:3.8-bullseye
```